# Binary search using c programming

Tags: c, search, binary

Given an array of integers which is sorted in ascending order, and an integer target, write a function to search target in the array. If the target exists, then return its index. Otherwise, return -1.

You must write an algorithm with O(log n) runtime complexity.

*I solved the above question using the following code:*

```
int search(int* nums, int numsSize, int target){

    int l = 0;
    int r = numsSize -1;
    int result = -1;
    
    while(l <= r)
    {
        int mid = (l + (r-l))/2;
        
        if(nums[mid] == target)
            return result = nums[mid];
        if(nums[mid] < target)
            return l = mid + 1;
        else
            return r = mid - 1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

But I am still not getting the right answer. Please help.

Comment: Under what conditions are you getting the wrong answer?  What is an array you are searching? for what target value? What result are you expecting, and what result are you getting?

Comment: If you have only 1 element in the array (`l == r`) you automatically return `-1` even if that element matches the target.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError The value returned should be `mid` as pointed out in Corina's answer below.

Answer (score 3):

You are returning the newly calculated `l` and `r` value.

```
if(nums[mid] < target)
    return l = mid + 1;
else
    return r = mid - 1;
```

You just need to update them and keep searching the element.

```
if(nums[mid] < target)
    l = mid + 1;
else
    r = mid - 1;
```

Comment: After making these changes, I am getting TIME LIMIT EXCEEDED as result

Answer (score 3):

Corrected code:

```
int search(int* nums, int numsSize, int target){

    int l = 0;
    int r = numsSize -1;
    int result = -1;
    printf("%d %d %d\n", numsSize, target, nums[0]);

    while(l <= r)
    {
        int mid = l + (r - l) / 2;
        
        if(nums[mid] == target)
            return result = mid;
        if(nums[mid] < target)
            l = mid + 1;
        else
            r = mid - 1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

The errors:

1. You computed wrongly the mid, it's not:

   int mid = (l + (r-l))/2;

Correct version is:

```
int mid = l + (r - l) / 2;
```

2. You should not use return here because you break the loop.

```
if(nums[mid] < target)
        return l = mid + 1;
    else
        return r = mid - 1;
```

3. 

```
    if(nums[mid] == target)
          return result = nums[mid];
```

Here you should return the mid, the position of the target value, not the value itself.

Comment: You don't need the assignment in `return result = mid;` (simply `return mid;`), and then you can eliminate `result` altogether and end with `return -1;`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this: It is Java though

```
 public int search(int[] nums, int target) {
    int l = 0;
    int r = nums.length - 1;
    while(l<=r){
        
        int mid = (l+r)/2;
        if(target == nums[l]){
            return l;
        } else if (target == nums[r]){
            return r;
        } else if(target == nums[mid]){
            return mid;
        }
        else if(target > nums[mid]){
            l = mid;
            r = r - 1;
        }
        else {
            l = l + 1;
            r = mid;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: This is a C question, providing java code with no explanation doesn't really answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

**solved using python**

```
def search(self, nums, target):
    
    lowerIndex = 0
    higherIndex = len(nums) -1

    while lowerIndex < higherIndex:
        middle = (lowerIndex + higherIndex) // 2
        mid_number = nums[middle]
    
        if mid_number == target:
            return middle
    
        elif mid_number > target:
            lowerIndex = middle + 1
        elif mid_number < target:
            higherIndex = middle -1
    return -1
```

Comment: It is written in the question that the author wants the code in `C` only.